# CentOS 7, smb service requires a `systemctl restart smb` to work

Tags: samba, centos7

CentOS 7, smb service requires a `systemctl restart smb` to work after rebooting. On each every reboot.

Right after a boot, connections to Samba simply hang and then fail.
Restarting the service makes it work permanently.

What causes this? And how can I delay it in such a way that I don't have to log into the machine?

Comment: Is it possible that the service is not starting rather than appearing to hang because it is not enabled (i.e. systemctl enable smb)?

Comment: yep, that was it... Not sure if you should make this into an answer or I should delete the question :))

Comment: @tchester You should make that into an answer, so the bounty doesn't go to waste :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SMB service is most likely not enabled which means that after each reboot you will need to manually start it. To enable the service so that it survives a reboot execute the following:

```
systemctl enable smb
```